# Hangfire Azure authorization denied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, hangfire

I have deployed my small application with Hangfire to Azure App service. (I've done this with another project)

I am trying to set it up with Azure Active Directory authorization. I went to the Azure portal and set it up in the app service's authentication/authorization settings: Turned on App service authentication, selected Azure Active Directory and added Configured (Express:Existing App) in the authentication providers menu (just like in the previous project). I then restart the app service.

Startup.cs contains:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHangfire(config => config
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseMemoryStorage());

            services.AddHangfireServer();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IWebHostEnvironment env,
            IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient,
            IRecurringJobManager recurringJobs)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions()
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new HangFireAuthorizationFilter() }
            });


            app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 5 });


            //backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello Hangfire job!!"));


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

HangFireAuthorizationFilter.cs contains:

```
public class HangFireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            //Can use this for NetCore
            return !context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
```

I publish to Azure successfully and login with my Azure account when prompted, and I get this message:
`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

I've enabled logging in the azure app and I get this error message:

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong? I am surely missing something but don't know what. If I disable the authorization from Azure, the deployment and the app itself works as intended.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error in the Azure App service settings/configs, the following changes solved my problem:

- Added full URL without route in "Authentication" in App Registration
- Removed "Power BI"-permission from API Permissions in App Registration
- Granted Admin Consent for all predefined permissions in    App
  Registration
- Changed "Action to take when request is not authenticated" to: "Log
  in with Azure Active Directory" in the App Service
  "Authentication/Authorization"

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, I suppose you miss the API permission in your AD App, please try the steps below.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find your AD App corresponding to the web app with the filter `All applications` -> `API permissions` -> add the **Delegated permission** `User.Read` in `Microsoft Graph`.

[image]

Then when you use the user account in your AAD tenant to login the web app, it will ask you to consent the permission `User.Read`, after consent and login successfully, it will work fine.

---

**Note:** To consent the permission with a normal user, make sure `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications` -> `User settings` -> `Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf` is set to `Yes`.

[image]

Comment: You were close, thank you for the answer!

Comment: @crystyxn What you did are not the tricks, they are not necessary. 1. The redirect url should always be `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`, 2. No need to remove any API permissions, you just need `User.Read` delegated permission. 3.`User.Read` is not admin consent required, so this step is also unnecessary. 4. You have already set it with Azure AD auth in your question, it is also not the reason.

Comment: @crystyxn Actually, the universal way to solve this issue is to choose the `Create new AD App` in this step - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings, it will configure all the things for you automatically.(this way will use `User.Read` in AAD Graph, not MS Graph, it is also ok).